# Does Inmobi works with Admob Mediation

Tags: admob, integration, inmobi

I am getting the following in logcat which might be the cause for NOT loading the Inmobi ads

```
    VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
VFY: dead code 0x000d-000f in Lcom/inmobi/commons/internal/ActivityRecognitionManager;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)V
VFY: dead code 0x0012-002c in Lcom/inmobi/commons/internal/ActivityRecognitionManager;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)V
Could not find method com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult, referenced from method com.inmobi.commons.internal.ActivityRecognitionManager.a
VFY: unable to resolve static method 7313: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionResult;.hasResult (Landroid/content/Intent;)Z
VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
VFY: dead code 0x0003-000f in Lcom/inmobi/commons/internal/ActivityRecognitionManager;.a (Landroid/content/Intent;)V
Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity', referenced from method com.inmobi.commons.internal.ActivityRecognitionManager.getDetectedActivity
VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1125 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity;) in Lcom/inmobi/commons/internal/ActivityRecognitionManager;
VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0009
VFY: dead code 0x000b-000f in Lcom/inmobi/commons/internal/ActivityRecognitionManager;.getDetectedActivity ()I
2): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4062a668
Could not find method android.os.Vibrator.hasVibrator, referenced from method com.inmobi.re.controller.JSUtilityController.c
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 908: Landroid/os/Vibrator;.hasVibrator ()Z
VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x01fc
Could not find method com.inmobi.re.container.IMWebView.isHardwareAccelerated, referenced from method com.inmobi.re.controller.JSUtilityController.c
VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9322: Lcom/inmobi/re/container/IMWebView;.isHardwareAccelerated ()Z
VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0217
VFY: dead code 0x01ff-0201 in Lcom/inmobi/re/controller/JSUtilityController;.c (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
VFY: dead code 0x021a-0228 in Lcom/inmobi/re/controller/JSUtilityController;.c (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
VFY: dead code 0x0234-0235 in Lcom/inmobi/re/controller/JSUtilityController;.c (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

1. I have "admob" , "inmobi" , "Mmedia" ad networks in admob mediation placement
2. My application is not Live yet and I am testing various ad networks vai admob mediation
3. I disabled all ad networks in mediation except "inmobi". Its not showing an adds and I can the above mentioned logcat logs

How I did the integration ????

1. Well I created login id's and registered app in the individual ad network websites and got the APP ID
2. Used that APP ID in corresponding ad networks in the mediation
3. My application main activity is using the Mediation ID
4. If I choose only "admob" and disable others, admob works and shows ads, But no ads from Inmobi

What I modified in the code??

1. Added 2 jar files(inmobi adapter and inmobi sdk) in libs folder
2. Added following in Menifest file

   android:name="com.inmobi.commons.analytics.androidsdk.IMAdTrackerReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">

Comment: Are you using the correct version of adapter and SDK? Also, android manifest needs IMBrowserActivity definition too. Please look at the integration once again..

Answer (score 5):

try the following steps:

1. Download the latest inmobi sdk from http://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/

   1. Download the latest inmobi adapter for admob mediation
   2. Add these jars to the libs folder and follow the admob integration steps as you have mentioned earlier.
   3. Ad the following in your application manifest:

.

```
<activity android:name="com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMBrowserActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
 <receiver
    android:name="com.inmobi.commons.analytics.androidsdk.IMAdTrackerReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

1. Do the necessary configuration on the admob site to enable inmobi ads

If you still face issues check if your inmobi application/property id  is in active state. If your appid is not active u can still test your integration by following this link [test inmobi integration](http://www.inmobi.com/support/art/23382291/21894911/setting-up-publisher-diagnostics/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gurnetkaur,
I found the issue.

Everything was correct in all the configuration files.
Issue was with the APP ID. since i have not published the APP in the market and it does not have any valid URL.
Inmobi do not send ads to apps under development.there must be valid market URL.

there are 2 solutions to test the ads in that situation.
1. Add test device with Inmobi
2. Get Test App ID from inmobi (i Got one from them)

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I am also trying the same and in the App in InMobi I can see the below message "Note that for apps without registered URLs, only test ads will be served, across all devices." so i think now dev apps also should work